# proxy_pass to different URLs in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to create a reverse proxy under one location for two different upstreams. Upstreams are so different that they have different prefixes in URL, but the rest is the same.

- https://foo.example.com/foo/api/get/this
- https://bar.example.net/bar/api/get/this

Non-working configuration:

```
    upstream foo{
        server https://foo.example.com/foo;
        server https://bar.example.net/bar backup;
    }

    server{
      ...
      location /foobar/(.+) {
         proxy_pass https://foo/$1?args
      }
   }
```

I know I can't use URL in 'upstream' section, and I know I can't use two servers in a `proxy_pass` directive, but is there any way to use nginx as 'failover balancer' for two different URLs?